# Implementation of Olingo visitLambdaExpression of ExpressionVisitor interface

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I am trying to implement lambda operators "any" and "all" provided by OData V4 using Olingo in Java. I cannot find any tutorial or any code snippet to understand the way lambda operators to be implemented using Oningo in Java.

I understand that I need to override visitLambdaExpression method of ExpressionVisitor interface but could not figure out exactly how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested: When evaluating the expression tree, the lambda expression first appears as a resource part in visitMember. So, look out for a URI resource part that is an instance of UriResourceLambdaAny or UriResourceLambdaAll.

I think visitLambdaExpression needs to be called from there yourself. There is no visitable expression of type LambdaExpression in Olingo. The available expression types are Alias, Binary, Enumeration, Expression, LambdaRef, Literal, Member, Method, TypeLiteral and Unary. LambdaRef defines the access to the lambda variable, not the expression.